# Limit question (to remove x to get a value of limit questions)

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to  3} \frac{(3-x)}{{\sqrt{1+x}}-\sqrt{7-x}}$$

In order to solve this, if we multiply (3-x) in the denominator and numerator, will it be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Multiply the denominator and numerator by $\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{7-x}$

and use $x\to3,x-3\to0\implies x-3\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i misread the question. but the question is asking x --> 3. So why don't you plug 3 into the whole thing? You should really think about if you can do it as f(x) at the first place, if f(3) exists, then done. If not, then you do some simplification, something like that.

Comment: At $x=3$, the denominator is $\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{4} = 0$.